# Can we use CodeIgniter without htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am beginner in CodeIgniter and facing issues with my `.htaccess` file. Is it necessary to use the `.htaccess` file with CodeIgniter?

Comment: you can... but I do not recommend it.

Comment: I agree with geggleto. Just research how to build a good htaccess file. Here's one place to start: http://www.farinspace.com/codeigniter-htaccess-file/

Comment: .htaccess is basically a webroot ini override. If you have control of your server you should consider configuring it to not rely on htaccess. A little google searching should point you in the right direction

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can but if you don't use a special web server like `nginx`, you can not remove `index.php` from URL's.

If you won't use `.htaccess` file on Apache web server, your URL's will shown like below (Actually you can remove it via `httpd.conf` but it is not recommended):

```
http://www.yourdomain.com/index.php/your-url
```

If you prefer to use nginx, you should edit `nginx.conf` file like below:

```
server {
        server_name domain.tld;

        root /your/codeigniter/folder;
        index index.html index.php;

        # set expiration of assets to MAX for caching
        location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)(\?[0-9]+)?$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }

        location / {
                # Check if a file or directory index file exists, else route it to index.php.
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        location ~* \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                include fastcgi.conf;
        }
}
```

You should add this piece between `html {}` tags in `nginx.conf`

If you prefer Apache + .htaccess and want to remove `index.php` thing, you should create an `.htaccess` file like below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Please check [Codeigniter URL Guide](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html) for all details. I also agree with @geggleto, .htaccess file is not just for index.php thing, you can do lots of things with htaccess.